# How can I calculate a given probability formula?

Tags: probability

I have $A,B,C$ as non empty occurrences and I know that $A,C$ are mutually exclusive (I mean they can't occur together)

I also have the next info($X^C$ means the opposite of $X$):
$P(A \ and \ B^C)=0.3$
$P(B|A)=P(B|C)=0.25$
$P(A^C \ and \ B^C \ and \ C^C) = 0.2$
$P(C \ and \ B^C)=0.15$

(sorry that I don't know how to format well)
I need to calculate both $P(A^C \ and \ B \ and \ C^C)$ and $P(B|A \ or \ C)$

The problem is I don't see the way of doing that, I have tried to play and open the expressions but I'm stuck I probably miss some formulas that could help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with Venn diagrams. Draw "sets" $A$, $B$ and $C$ and compute the probabilities for every of $8$ regions. For formatting, you can use `\text{and}` instead of just `and` etc.

Comment: @Antoine how would you draw something like $P(B|A)$ in Venn diagram? I'm trying to draw it but I just realized I've never seen how to draw a 'given' probability in Venn

Comment: What do you mean by "and" ? Intersection ($\cap$) or union ($\cup$) ?

Comment: @callculus I mean intersection and by "or" I mean union

Comment: One hint: $A$ is a subset of $B^c$. Therefore $P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)=0.3$.

Comment: @callculus how did you conclude that $A$ is a subset of $B^C$?

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. Only A and C are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$p(A\cdot B^c)=0.3$

$p(B|A)=0.25$, so $p(A|B)=0.1$

$p(B^c\cdot C)=0.15$

$p(B|C)=0.25$, so $p(B\cdot C)=0.05$

So far we have accounted for every area except $p(A^cBC^c)$ and $p(A^cB^cC^c)$, so they must total 0.4. We are given $p(A^cB^cC^c)=0.2$, so $p(A^cBC^c)=0.2$

Finally, you want $p(A^cBC^c)$, which is 0.2, and you want $p(B|A\text{ or }C)$. To get that note that $p(A\text{ or }C)=0.6$ and $p(B\text{ and } (A\text{ or }C))=0.15$, so $p(B|A\text{ or }C)=0.25$

Comment: Thanks how did you work with the "given" probability I'm having hard time to understand how to draw it in the Venn. You said that $P(B|A)=0.25$ hence $P(A|B)=0.1$ if we had to mark the area of $P(B|A)$ where would have it been? its not the same as $P(A \ and \ B)$ right?

Comment: You cannot mark the area $p(B|A)$ in the Venn diagram. $p(B|A)$ is the prob that $B$ is true given that $A$ is true. So it is $\frac{p(B\text{ and }A)}{p(A)}$.

Comment: Oh so how did you make the step in line 2 and line 4? (how did you find out $P(A|B)$ and $P(B \ and \ C)$)

Comment: Let $p(A\text{ and }B)=x$. We know that $p(A\text{ and }B^c)=0.3$, so $0.25=p(B|A)=\frac{x}{x+0.3}$. Hence $x=0.1$. Similarly for the other one.

Comment: Oh I see now you used the $P(A)=P(A \ and \ B) + P(A \ and \ B^C)$ too, thanks I'll keep going over that solution making sure I get it all